# contact.find phonegap IOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Hi I'm trying to fetch the contacts from the phonebook using contact.find but i can't get it to work...

The addressbook is displayed and the when I choose a contact i get the ID but I don't get the rest of the information from this user that im trieng to alert in the onContactFound() function... what can be wrong??

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            function pickContact()
            {
                var options = {};
                navigator.contacts.chooseContact(onContactSelected, options);
            }

            function onContactSelected(id)
            {
                alert("Contact ID = " + id);

                //TODO: How to look up the contact object by ID???
                var options = new ContactFindOptions();
                options.filter = "" + id;
                var fields = ["id","displayName","addresses"];
                navigator.contacts.find(fields, onContactFound, onContactFailure, options);
            }

            function onContactFound(contacts) {
                alert(contacts.length + " contact(s) found");  //ex. 1 contact(s) found
                alert("ID = " + contacts[0].id + ", Name = " + contacts[0].Name);
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contacts

Answer (score 0):

Property is name (or displayName), not Name, I suspect. Change contacts[0].Name.

Comment: hmm, i tried but the thing is that the alert(contacts.lenght) isn't diplayed ether so it must be a break earlyer, but thanks for the input!

Comment: Implement your error handler to see if anything is being returned. Have you previously verified that the id being supplied exists in your contacts? May want to comment out second alert.